# JLine3 "Unable to create a system terminal" after build

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jline, jline3, jansi

I just tried to implement JLine with Jansi, but it throws always the same `UnsupportedOperationException` referring to `org.jline.terminal.impl.jansi.JansiSupportImpl#winSysTerminal`. Inspecting this method there is only one simple `if` which decides on this exception.

[image: Fernflower decompiled of given source]

So the version numbers must be the problem... to check them I copied the code which detects the versions to my source

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String v = Ansi.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    System.out.println(Ansi.class.getPackage());
    if (v != null) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)([\\.-]\\S+)?").matcher(v);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Major: " + Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
            System.out.println("Minor: " + Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
        }
    }

    //System.setProperty("jansi.passthrough", "true");
    AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

    String prompt = Ansi.ansi()
            .eraseScreen()
            .fg(Ansi.Color.BLUE).bold().a("Console")
            .fgBright(Ansi.Color.BLACK).bold().a(" > ")
            .reset().toString();

    Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder()
            .system(true)
            .dumb(false)
            .encoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
            .name("Terminal")
            .jna(false)
            .jansi(true)
            .build();

    LineReader reader = LineReaderBuilder.builder()
            .terminal(terminal)
            .build();

    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine(prompt)) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

The outcome surprised me: 
While it returns `package org.fusesource.jansi, jansi, version 1.17.1, Major: 1, Minor: 17` in IntelliJ, but the console does not work because intellijs virtual console, it returns only `package org.fusesource.jansi` when I run it from command line after building. This must be caused by intellij removing the manifests, that contain the information. They cannot be packed because they got the same name as the manifest I need to run the jar file.

Do you guys know any solution or workaround? How do you handle with this exception? Or is there anything I failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're embedding Jansi in your own jar.
If you, you should be able to hack the `MANIFEST.MF` of you jar to include the relevant information for Jansi.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: peter
...

Name: org/fusesource/jansi/
Implementation-Version: 1.17.1
```

Comment: You little hackerman - but it works ^^ Let me know if there is a solution without getting in danger that I will need this properties in the manifest for myself at anytime